# Why Apache Camel result on Graceful shutdown

Tags: kotlin, apache-camel, smpp

Hello  I have an app written in Kotlin and using Spring boot Framework and Apache Camel:
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/smpp-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration

So I am new in Smpp protocol I am suppuse trying to connecto to SMC simulator so I guess my
"client" should be wait for a message from SMC in this case when I run the application it
appears just stop and anymore. As it just stops  I would think something is wrong.

```
   @Bean
    fun camelContextConfiguration(): CamelContextConfiguration{
        return object : CamelContextConfiguration {
            override fun afterApplicationStart(camelContext: CamelContext?) {
                logger.info("*********************************************************************************")
                //var query : Query?
                //val oldRoute : List<Route> = camelContext!!.routes
                camelContext!!.routes
                //logger.info("Old Routes")
                //logger.info(oldRoute.size.toString())
//                for(route:Route in oldRoute) {
//                    logger.info("Route with routeId {} is deleted",route.id)
//                    camelContext.stopRoute(route.id)
//                    camelContext.removeRoute(route.id)
//                }
                camelContext.isUseMDCLogging=true
                logger.info("ROUTES")
                    val routeDefinition = RouteDefinition()
                    routeDefinition.id="1"
                   routeDefinition.onException(Exception::class.java).handled(true)
                           .process(exceptionProcessor())
                           .end()
                   
                    routeDefinition.from("smpp://smppclient@smscsim.melroselabs.com:2775?password=password&enquireLinkTimer=3000&transactionTimer=5000&systemId=145244&systemType='Receiver'")
                    routeDefinition.to("log:com.app.smppdispenser.infraestructure.smpp?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
                    routeDefinition.process(messageProcessor())
                    camelContext.addRouteDefinition(routeDefinition)
                   //routeDefinition.setHeader("CamelSmppCommandId", constant("query_sm"))
                    //routeDefinition.setHeader("CamelSmppSequenceNumber", constant("1"))
                    logger.info("Route is added with routeId {} ",routeDefinition.id)

                //}
                logger.info("CamelConfiguration afterApplicationStart OK")
            }
            override fun beforeApplicationStart(camelContext: CamelContext?) {
                logger.info("CamelConfiguration beforeApplicationStart")
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the log>

> 2021-06-06 10:37:06.824  INFO 5604 --- [           main]
> o.a.c.s.boot.CamelContextConfiguration   : ROUTES 2021-06-06
> 10:37:07.538  INFO 5604 --- [           main]
> org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : Connected to
> smscsim.melroselabs.com/18.200.51.80 2021-06-06 10:37:07.541  INFO
> 5604 --- [ession@31859960] org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            :
> Starting PDUReaderWorker 2021-06-06 10:37:07.817  INFO 5604 --- [
> main] org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : Other side reports
> SMPP interface version 34 2021-06-06 10:37:07.817  INFO 5604 --- [
> main] org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : Changing processor
> degree to 3 2021-06-06 10:37:07.819  INFO 5604 --- [           main]
> o.a.camel.component.smpp.SmppConsumer    : Connected to:
> smpp://145244@smscsim.melroselabs.com:2775 2021-06-06 10:37:07.820
> INFO 5604 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext
> : Route: 1 started and consuming from:
> smpp://smppclient@smscsim.melroselabs.com:2775?enquireLinkTimer=3000&password=xxxxxx&systemId=145244&systemType=%27Receiver%27&transactionTimer=5000
> 2021-06-06 10:37:07.821  INFO 5604 --- [           main]
> o.a.c.s.boot.CamelContextConfiguration   : Route is added with routeId
> 1  2021-06-06 10:37:07.821  INFO 5604 --- [           main]
> o.a.c.s.boot.CamelContextConfiguration   : CamelConfiguration
> afterApplicationStart OK 2021-06-06 10:37:07.936  INFO 5604 --- [
> Thread-2] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing
> org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@2cf3d63b:
> startup date [Sun Jun 06 10:36:55 COT 2021]; root of context hierarchy
> 2021-06-06 10:37:07.944  INFO 5604 --- [       Thread-2]
> o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase
> 2147483647 2021-06-06 10:37:07.945  INFO 5604 --- [       Thread-2]
> o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.20.1
> (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down 2021-06-06 10:37:07.946  INFO
> 5604 --- [       Thread-2] o.a.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy   :
> Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
> 2021-06-06 10:37:08.163  WARN 5604 --- [ession@31859960]
> org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : IOException while reading:
> Socket Closed 2021-06-06 10:37:08.164  INFO 5604 --- [ - ShutdownTask]
> o.a.camel.component.smpp.SmppConsumer    : Disconnected from:
> smpp://145244@smscsim.melroselabs.com:2775 2021-06-06 10:37:08.164
> INFO 5604 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy
> : Route: 1 shutdown complete, was consuming from:
> smpp://smppclient@smscsim.melroselabs.com:2775?enquireLinkTimer=3000&password=xxxxxx&systemId=145244&systemType=%27Receiver%27&transactionTimer=5000
> 2021-06-06 10:37:08.165  INFO 5604 --- [ession@31859960]
> org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : PDUReaderWorker stop
> 2021-06-06 10:37:08.166  INFO 5604 --- [       Thread-2]
> o.a.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Graceful shutdown of 1
> routes completed in 0 seconds 2021-06-06 10:37:08.202  INFO 5604 --- [
> Thread-2] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel
> 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 1.629 seconds 2021-06-06 10:37:08.203  INFO 5604 --- [       Thread-2]
> o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.20.1
> (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.257 seconds Process finished
> with exit code 0

Edit
I have added thse option: camel.springboot.main-run-controller = true then  I see  this new line in my log but it finish of  the same way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there are some options:

- add a spring boot starter web which starts a web server and keep the application running
- use a property as explained here: https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/3.7.x/spring-boot.html#SpringBoot-Keepingapplicationalive

Comment: Hello I have already this like my dependency:  'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'.

Comment: I'd recommend to upgrade to a more recent camel version and if the problem persists to try to create a reproducer so we can have a look

Comment: Thanks! I have resolved already  of this way I downloaded gradle on my pc. Next I go to my dir project and execute the folowing: gradlew bootRun, all from my cmd. I tried to execute  the project from my STS in 2 versions and Android Studio in some earlies intents.